# ImportError: cannot import name 'deque' from 'collections' for Python when trying to create venv v3.10

Tags: python-3.x

I've looked at all the other stack overflow problems related to this one and I can't seem to find a solution. I was wondering what I can do to resolve this error?

This is the command I put in
`python3 -m nenv nenv`

`ImportError: cannot import name 'deque' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)`

I tried updating from " collections import deque " to " collections import Deque" but that didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include the exact import statement you're using? It should be `from collections import deque`

Comment: This is the import line (I think..)

```try:
    from collections import deque
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    _collections_abc.MutableSequence.register(deque)```

Comment: ```python3 -m nenv nenv``` This is the command that I used